# Div does not stretch to 100% height

Tags: html, css

Why has this div not 100% height the parent has 100% and the div too! The green color should stretch to the bottom!

Do I have overlooked something?

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/vExZpe

```
<div style="height:100%;background:green;">
  test
</div>

body, hmtl{
  height:100%;
}

div{
  height:100%;   
}
```

Comment: I get downvoted for a grammar I have not seen. In what a world do we live?

Comment: A world in which not "seeing" a "grammar" does not make a good, useful Stack Overflow question. You did not get downvoted; your question did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo. `hmtl` should be `html`.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:100%;background:green;">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: you beat me to it. couldnt let me go 2/2 on typo answers huh? haha

Comment: You could also go with: `body,html { width:100vw; height:100vh; }`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl - Those units are [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) on IE.